# HTTP POST to Google Sheets (via Apps Script) not importing JSON body message contents?

Tags: javascript, json, http, google-apps-script, post

I've designed a web app that posts order information to Google Sheets via HTTP POST and Google Apps Script. However, I am struggling to POST and extract the order information from the body JSON. I have tried 2 different methods and they both output the similar information but with the same data type - FileUpload. I've even attempted to import it as parameters as FormData() but repeatedly appending parameters didn't feel quite right.

Method 1

```
function method1() {
  var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var data = JSON.stringify({ firstName: "Jay", lastName: "Smith" });
  xml.open("POST", url, true);
  /*   xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json"); */
  xml.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xml.readyState === 4 && xml.status === 200) {
      alert(xml.responseText);
    }
  };
  xml.send(data);
}
```

Output

```
{postData=FileUpload, contextPath=, contentLength=38.0, parameters={}, parameter={}, queryString=}
```

Notice how the setRequestHeader() function is commented. No output would occur if it was uncommented making the content type set to JSON. Why will it not work?

Method 2

```
function method2() {
  const body = {
    firstName: "Jay",
    lastName: "Smith",
  };
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  };

  fetch(url, options).then((res) => res.json());
}
```

Output

```
{contextPath=, parameters={}, parameter={}, queryString=, postData=FileUpload, contentLength=38.0}
```

Method 3 (Should I even consider this?)

```
function method3() {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("firstName", "Jay");
  formData.append("lastName", "Smith");
  fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
  }).then((res) => res.json());
}
```

Output

```
{contentLength=243.0, parameter={firstName=Jay, lastName=Smith}, queryString=, contextPath=, parameters={lastName=[Ljava.lang.Object;@6c4aece6, firstName=[Ljava.lang.Object;@3c461e46}}
```

The content length is considerably larger... this does not seem like an effective concept.

---

Google Apps Script doPost() Function

```
function doPost(e) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEETID).getSheetByName('Testing Inputs');
  sheet.getRange(3,1).setValue(e); // To display POST output
  const data = JSON.parse(request.postData.contents)
  sheet.getRange(5,1).setValue(data['firstName']) // Not writing "Jay"? 
  sheet.getRange(5,2).setValue(data['lastName']) // Not writing "Smith"?
}
```

In general, it appears data is coming through as body message content judging by the contentLength output but is it not JSON considering the postData is FileUpload? That may cause my Apps Script nor to be able to extract it right? Also, I thought I read that using fetch() is considerably better than using XMLHttpRequest() so should I be using my Method 2?  Still not sure what am I doing wrong to populate it in individual cells in sheets using Apps Script?

Any help is appreciated!

Output Using `sheet.getRange(3,1).setValue(JSON.stringify(e))`

```
{"parameter":{},"postData":{"contents":"{\"firstName\":\"Jay\",\"lastName\":\"Smith\"}","length":38,"name":"postData","type":"text/plain"},"parameters":{},"contentLength":38,"queryString":"","contextPath":""}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing scripts and `FileUpload` of "Output". Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Where are your output lines taken from? Is that what's logged in the spreadsheet cell (3,1)?

Comment: @Tanaike yes, what I am saying is the POST content type should be JSON but instead it is sending as FileUpload which I believe is the reason I can’t extract first name and last name from the body message. I believe the postData should be application/JSON but I don’t understand why it won’t POST when I manually set it (such as where it was commented in method 1). In theory, it being uncommented would change the output to application/JSON instead of FileUpload.

Comment: @AaronDuniganAtLee yes, the output lines are taken from what’s logged in the spreadsheet cell (3,1)

Comment: Can you change the logging to `sheet.getRange(3,1).setValue(JSON.stringify(e))` and report back the result? This may expand the contents of `e.postData`.

Comment: @AaronDuniganAtLee sure, I added it to the bottom of the question. It did expand it enough to see the body message! Any idea how to add each to a cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the output provided by `sheet.getRange(3,1).setValue(JSON.stringify(e))` (I'm not sure which of your methods generated this, but that method looks like it's the right one), your `doPost` as written should work, with one modification: I don't see a variable `request` defined, so I assume you intend `request` to be the http request object, which in an Apps Script web app is defined by the `e` parameter passed to the `doPost` ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters)).  Therefore change this line

```
const data = JSON.parse(request.postData.contents)
```

to this one

```
const data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents)
```

Comment: @FrozenXeno You're welcome. Please consider editing your question to indicate which of your 3 methods generated that output, for the sake of future visitors to this question, and consider marking this answer as correct for the same reason.